# Delete Scheduled Job using ScheduledTasks class

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am using ScheduledTasks over at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Although I can't seem to find an example of how you delete a Scheduled Task in thier documentation, although they state you can do, could someone provide a basic example please

Comment: Your link says you delete it through the ScheduledTasks object.  Does it have a Delete method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your link:

> You use a ScheduledTasks object to
>   access the individual tasks. Each task
>   has a name, the same as its file name
>   without the extension. From the
>   ScheduledTasks object you can obtain
>   the names of all the tasks currently
>   scheduled. There are methods to
>   create, open and delete tasks, all of
>   which use the task's name.

So it would be:

```
ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\DALLAS");
st.DeleteTask("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

yea, its the part of library.

```
public static ScheduledTasks ScTask = null
ScTask .DeleteTask("Task Name")
```